# Who is detective Clausen's brother?

Tags: plot-explanation, dark

In the 7. episode of season 2 we see detective Clausen looking at a photo which I assume was from his youth and standing next to him is his missing brother Alexander. When I saw this scene I thought immediately that the brother was Noah. I did check that scene a few more times and I think that there is a strong resemblance to young Noah but I can't be sure.

Was there ever any information from the producers about that scene or about Alexander Köhler in fact being Noah?

Comment: Can we edit this to avoid spoilers in the title of the question?

Answer (score 5):

Spoilers from the ending of season 2:

> Based on what the show has told us, Clausen's brother is the person
>  that Alexander Kohler (Boris Niewald in reality) presumably killed
>  before meeting Regina and took over his identity.
>
>  Young Noah was called Hanno Tauber at birth and was alive in 1921, as
>  was his sister Agnes Nielsen, who later killed him. Also, in 1921, he wasn't a time traveler yet. So he was killed at a different time, not in 1986 as probably was Clausen's brother.

All these facts lead to the conclusion, that Noah can't be Clausen's brother.